# Uncaught type error when trying to loop through two element arrays at the same time

Tags: javascript, dom

`enter code here`i dunno why it gives me that error "Uncaught typeError: cannot set the property of innerHTML to undefined."
for 2 hours it was pain in the ass trying to figure out what's wrong but still didn't conclude anything....
that's my code:

```
    if(window.addEventListener){
        for(i=0; i<inArray.length; i++){
            inArray[i].addEventListener('keyup',function() {
                if(this.value !== '') document.body.removeChild(text[i]);
                else document.body.appendChild(text[i]);
            },false)
        }
    }else{
        for(i=0; i<inArray.length; i++){
            inArray[i].attachEvent('onkeyup',function() {
                if(this.value !== '') document.body.removeChild(text[i]);
                else document.body.appendChild(text[i]);
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is that the exact error message?

Comment: `inArray[i].attachEvent('onkeyup', function() {` won't reference any item within the array, as it is outside the scope of the for statement.

Comment: Why is finding the primary, central "event handler in a loop" question so hard?